# Ajax NSURLCache Issue still gets undefined response

Tags: ios, ajax, nsurlcache

Hey I have Checked the web and tried all over the suggested solutions

but still get UNdefined

const NSString *kAppHost = @"myApp.example.org";

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {

NSURL *url = [request URL];

// check the host to see if Javascript is trying to send a request to our app's "fake" host
if ([[url host] caseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *) kAppHost] == NSOrderedSame) {

    NSString *action = nil;
    if ([[url pathComponents] count] > 1) { // use index 1 since index 0 is the '/'
        // Theoretically, we could use the :controller/:action/:id pattern here, but for simplicity we'll just do
        // /:action
        action = [[url pathComponents] objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    NSString *query = [url query];
    NSString *method = [request HTTPMethod];
    NSDictionary *params = nil;

    // we also want to extract any arguments passed in the request. In a GET, we can get these from the URL query
    // string. In requests with entities, we can get this from the request body (assume www-form encoded for our purposes
    // here, but we could also handle JSON entities)
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"POST"] || [method isEqualToString:@"PUT"]) {
        NSString *body = nil;
        body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        params = [NSDictionary gtm_dictionaryWithHttpArgumentsString:body];
    } else {
        params = [NSDictionary gtm_dictionaryWithHttpArgumentsString:query];
    }

    // construct a NativeAction object to transport this request message to our handler in native code
    //NativeAction *nativeAction;// = [[NativeAction alloc] initWithAction:action method:method params:params];
    NSError *error1 = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];// = [[self.delegate handleAction:nativeAction error:&error1] mutableCopy];

    [result setObject:@"1234" forKey:@"guid"];

    // if we got an error, assign it in the hash we'll pass back to javascript
    if (error1) {
        [result setObject:@{
         @"code" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:error1.code],
         @"message" : [error1 localizedDescription]

         }          forKey:@"error"];
    }

    // Lastly, we need to construct an NSCachedURLResponse object to return from this method. This is the response
    // (headers + body) that will be passed back to our jQuery callback
    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = nil;
    if (result) {
        NSString *jsonString = [[[SBJsonWriter alloc] init] stringWithObject:result];
        NSData *jsonBody = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : @"*", @"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : @"Content-Type, Origin, Accept, x-requested-with", @"" : @"GET, POST"};
        NSHTTPURLResponse *urlresponse = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:request.URL statusCode:200 HTTPVersion:@"1.1" headerFields:headers];

        cachedResponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:urlresponse data:jsonBody];

        NSLog(@"cachedResponse %@", cachedResponse);
        NSLog(@"cachedResponse data %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[cachedResponse data] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    }

    return cachedResponse;
}

// if not matching our custom host, allow system to handle it
return [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

}

Here I see everything is ok but in the ajax i get undefined

```
        function GetDataIphone() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://myApp.example.org/contacts",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("getdata");
                alert(data);
                $('#message')[0].innerHTML = data.responseText;
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                $('#message')[0].innerHTML ="ERROR" +  ex.message;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar approach and never succeeded in getting it to work with POST. However, there is a much better alternative: you can use `NSURLProtocol` stack to intercept and handle any request.

[WebViewProxy](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewProxy) component provides a reusable easy-to-use implementation.